# AWK get avarage value with group by 2 fields

Tags: bash, awk, metrics

I finded how to get summary value grouping column by PID:

```
iotop -botqqqk -n 10 |  awk '{print $13,$2,$5}'| sort -rnk 1  | awk '                         
  { a[$2] += $3 }
  END {
    for (i in a) {
      printf "top_10_read{pid=\"%s\",name=\"%s\"} %s\n", i, $1, a[i] | "sort -rnk2";
    }
  }               
'
```

But I need to get sorted average value "DISK READ" grouping it by PID and PROCESS NAME.

I finded the ready solution: https://github.com/ncabatoff/process-exporter/. 
But I think that it has not enough details. I already have some "messy" scripts to export info about processes:

```
echo "TOP 10 CPU"
ps -A -rss -o comm,pcpu | awk -v cpus="$(nproc --all)" '
  { a[$1] += $2 }
  END {
    for (i in a) {
      printf "top_10_cpu{process=\"%s\"} %s\n", i, a[i]/cpus | "sort -rnk2";
    }
  }               
' | head -n 10

echo "TOP 10 RAM"
ps -A -rss -o comm,pmem | awk '                         
  { a[$1] += $2 }
  END {
    for (i in a) {
      printf "top_10_ram{process=\"%s\"} %s\n", i, a[i] | "sort -rnk2";
    }
  }               
' | head -n 10

echo "TOP 10 RSS"
ps -A -o comm,rss | awk '
  { a[$1] += $2 }
  END {
    for (i in a) {
      printf "top_10_rss{process=\"%s\"} %s\n", i, a[i]/1024 | "sort -g -rk2,2";
    }
  }
' | head -n 10

echo "TOP 10 VSZ"
ps -A -o comm,vsz | awk '
  { a[$1] += $2 }
  END {
    for (i in a) {
      printf "top_10_vsz{process=\"%s\"} %s\n", i, a[i]/1024 | "sort -g -rk2,2";
    }
  }
' | head -n 10

echo "TOP 10 SZ"
 ps -A -o comm,sz | awk '
  { a[$1] += $2 }
  END {
    for (i in a) {
      printf "top_10_sz{process=\"%s\"} %s\n", i, a[i]/1024 | "sort -g -rk2,2";
    }
  }
' | head -n 10
```

But also going to get info about TCP connection status by each process.

Is this cleaver solution in Your opinion or maybe I just waste my time and there is some ready option?

Sample of input:

```
 #iotop -botqqqk -n 10 |  awk '{print $13,$2,$5}'| sort -rnk 1
    glusterfsd 23976 0.00
    glusterfsd 23976 0.00
    glusterfsd 23975 122.89
    glusterfsd 23975 116.36
```

Sample of expected output:

```
    glusterfsd 23976 0.00
    glusterfsd 23975 119.625
```

Where "119.625" average DISK READ valu for PID 23975.

Regards

Comment: Please post sample of input and sample of expected output with code tags for better understanding of question.

Comment: When I hear "group by fields" and stats things like average, I think [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) as the tool of choice.

Comment: Why do you search for better solutions? And define "messy" please -- as far as I can see, these are good solutions for different use cases. So which use case are you planning to optimize?

Comment: _> Please post sample of input and sample of expected output with code tags for better understanding of question._ Update post. Thanks.

Comment: _> When I hear "group by fields" and stats things like average, I think GNU datamash as the tool of choice_ thanks, I will definitely try this

Comment: _>Why do you search for better solutions?_ Cause this can save my time _> And define "messy" please -- as far as I can see, these are good solutions for different use cases._ I'm not a coder, so I can't evaluate the elegance of the written lines. _So which use case are you planning to optimize?_ I'm looking for ready prometheus exporter for tcp stack states per every process.

Comment: @gremlintv2 FYI: if you want the person you replied be notified, you should `@` them like this comment did.  btw, [this](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.html) might help you. Also you can check `man awk`.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55060578/edit) your question, remove unrelated codes, produce relatively complete example of input and the according expected output.  You can check this: [mcve]. After you edited your question, it will go into reopen review queue, and veterans here will decide whether help you to reopen it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1st Solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
your_comand | awk '{a[$1,$2]++;b[$1,$2]+=$NF} END{for(i in a){print i,b[i]/a[i]}}'
```

---

---

***2nd Solution:*** In case you want to print output in same order of Input_file's 1st and 2nd field order then try following.

```
your_command | awk 'BEGIN{SUBSEP=" "} !c[$1,$2]++{d[++count]=$1 OFS $2} {a[$1,$2]++;b[$1,$2]+=$NF} END{for(i=1;i<=count;i++){print d[i],b[d[i]]/a[d[i]]}}'
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** BY seeing OP's tried code trying to do this within single `awk` itself though not tested at all(since sample output of command `iotop -botqqqk -n 10` is NOT provided).

```
iotop -botqqqk -n 10 | awk 'BEGIN{SUBSEP=" "} !c[$13,$2]++{d[++count]=$13 OFS $2} {a[$13,$2]++;b[$13,$2]+=$5} END{for(i=1;i<=count;i++){print d[i],b[d[i]]/a[d[i]]}}'
```

Comment: @gremlintv2, could you please check this once and let me know?

Comment: Sorry for delay and thancks You much the firest solution works